# Open & Manipulate Records of the .xcdatamodeld-File / SQLite?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

I'm trying to write my first iPhone-App, which should be data-driven.
Now I have some problems with providing an output - and I'm not sure how well the insert goes in the first place...

So what I want to do now (or: what I would do with a desktop/server-Application) is to check the DB-Content and manipulate them for testing...

BUT I can't figure out how to open the DB behind my data-model-settings.
On the internet, I found some tips that I can find the sqlite-file within the .xcdatamodeld-folder.
So I downloaded the SQLiteManager - but when I tried to open the file, I get an "the file is encryptet"-message.
I never added a password, neither is it my root-password.

So how can I open the file? Or is there even a solution within XCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced with same question. And my investigation's thread leads me to iOS developer library [example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Locations/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008406).

The main idea is creation of coordinator (link) between our datamodel and *.sqlite file. And this file we can observe, edit, copy and import.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext {

    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
    }
    return managedObjectContext;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];    
    return managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Locations.sqlite"]];

    NSError *error;
    persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
        // Handle the error.
    }    

    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

And it seems, that, during work with DB, *.sqlite would be created in ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/*-*-***-***/Documents